# C# summarizes the big variables

Tags: c#

I have a string variable that comes from a web service and because the response size of this web service is too large, the c# removes part of the string and replaces it with '...'.but when I save the string in the file is correct.
For example, the received data is:

> 'This is sample Text'

What the debugger shows me and the program works with is:

> 'Thi ... ext'

Comment: If you save the string to a file, and it is then correct, it is also correct in memory. The debugger might try to shorten the string, as you've noticed. What is the question here? Does your program fail or is it only the debugger that is showing it like that?

Comment: when i save the answer in a file, the text is complete. but when application try to work with this, text is brief.i do not know where the problem come from?

Comment: "try to work with this", can you give examples of how you try to work with it where it becomes shortened? Are you placing it in a label on a form somewhere, or otherwise trying to display it? Those components might have properties that control how they deal with text that is too long to fit in the space allocated to the control on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your string is complete when saved to file, it is merely the debugger showing you a truncated representation of the string.

If you need to to extract the complete string from the debugger, you can right-click it there and select "copy string" from the popup menu, then paste it somewhere (e.g. Notepad) to read it.